# Why don't I need to write these last two parameters? (self, first, last)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + "." + last + "@company.com"

    def fullname(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first, self.last)
```

So in `fullname()` you're supposed to only use `self`. I don't understand why I shouldn't have to write the first and last parameters.

Comment: Because that's how class properties work?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of: "`you're supposed to only use self`"?

Comment: What do you mean by "only using self"? You *do* use `self.first` and `self.last`, and you *could* use `self.pay` and `self.email` as well.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you think you're not supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709832/3715522) has a fairly detailed answer (and should explain the purpose of self) but to summarize:

Python uses the `self` argument (you can use any variable name instead, but it MUST be the first one in methods of a class and it MUST be remain identical in that class) to refer to the instance of the class the method is being called from and automatically passes that parameter for you whenever you call the method.

Thus, the `self` argument will have access to all the object's instance variables. In this case you declared `self.first`, `self.last`, `self.pay`, and `self.email` in your `__init__` function which turned all of those variables into instance variables. That means that any method that gets called on that instance has access to them by calling `self.<variable_name>` just like you setup in the `__init__`.

Comment: That should be: "all of those variables into **instance** variables".

Comment: @MCBama so any function I define inside that class has acess to the variables in the __init__ method?

Comment: @DiogoDaniel Essentially. But you can actually define instance variables in any method at any time. As soon as you define a variable on `self` that variable becomes an instance variable. Which means if you had some function `def foo(self)` that declared `self.bar = True` and that method was called, you could access `self.bar` inside your `firstname(self)` function if you wanted.

Comment: The reason you already have access to all the ones declared within the `__init__` function is because the init is the constructor and gets auto called whenever an instance is created.

Comment: @DiogoDaniel Happy to help :). Hopefully cleared some stuff up for ya there. Good luck on the rest of your project!